# Partitioning large table in snowflake through a custom partitioner

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a large table in snowflake which has more than 55 BILLION records. Users retrieve data from this table by providing YEAR and a SERIAL_NUMBER as the predicate. It takes a lot of time to retrieve the records. We do not want to enable auto clustering as that is becoming expensive for us. We have, therefore, come up with the following approach. I wanted to take inputs on this approach.

*We are dividing the table into multiple partitions. For example if the table name is TABLE_XYZ. We are creating physical tables for each year like TABLE_XYZ_2016, TABLE_XYZ_2017, TABLE_XYZ_2018, TABLE_XYS_2019, TABLE_XYZ_2020. The latest year table is which gets changed frequently, the others are largely untouched. We have written a partitioner/splitter which reads a source similar table and splits the records by year and loads them in the corresponding year table ordering by year and serial_number. We have also created a view on top of all these tables. The idea is people who will need all years will go against the view, people who are interested in a certain year will go against the physical year table. We are expecting that this will reduce the time to retrieve the data. However, if there is a new year(lets say 2021), we will have to create that table and also redefine the view. I have not been able to find a way to create a dynamic view.*

Please let me know if this approach has any loop holes.

Thanks

Comment: I believe ,The "In built" micropartition and clustering key will also  do the same thing. Once you create clutster key on date columns , the scanning will prune those previous dates untill there is not DML for those previous dates. Also automatic refresh will also be for newer dates only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a far simpler way of achieving incredible performance using cluster keys.  See the documentation here:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html

In summary, create a cluster key on (YEAR, SERIAL_NUMBER) and in background Snowflake will automatically recluster (sort) the data by those keys.  Initially, this will probably re-sequence the entire table, but subsequently, it will only re-sort newly added values.

I did a test on a billion-row table where I created a unique sequence and put a cluster key on it performing a random look-up by the key and each fetch returned in milliseconds with just one I/O.

Snowflake also has a customer in the USA with over a PETABYTE of data in a single table (yes, 1,000 terabytes) which uses the same technique to achieve terrific query performance against the most recently added data.

To help tune the performance, I'd recommend (if possible) load the data as it arrives in YEAR format.  IE.  If you're doing a bulk load of several years, load one year at a time.  Otherwise don't worry.

You can then remove your physical partitioning and views and have Snowflake keep the entire solution clean and automatically updated.

You will find the background clustering will have an initial cost to sort the data, but subsequently, there should be a little cost involved, and the performance gains will be worth the effort.

Comment: Hi John, we did evaluate this option but for our use case, it is getting a costly affair. We may still go for auto reclustering but that will be for the latest year table only since the old year data hardly changes

Comment: If your data is already “naturally clustered” the recluster will cost nothing as the data will be clustered already.  On the question of cost.  Estimate the time and charge for the alternative solution. You may find the people cost hugely outweighs the compute cost of clustering the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any database offers views addressing non-existing tables ;) What you can do is:

(easiest): create 10 or 20 empty "future" tables and add them to your view. They are going to be empty so they won't affect performance

(harder): create a job that would run somewhere end of the year and create the new yearly table and recreate the view

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach. I was trying to do this from the program. This approach will save some processing

Answer (score 0):

If the history that was loaded into your table is unchanging then the cost of reclustering the table will be its highest on the first recluster. It should become cheaper over time, right?

If you didn't want to use auto re-clustering for some reason, why don't you do what you're doing now but into a single table? Run series of select queries where you order by the `year` and `SERIAL_NUMBER` and insert into a new table. To me, it doesn't make sense to split it into multiple tables.

Comment: If i do it on the single table, the clustering will go bad again as new data gets inserted into the latest year, right?